# Is this LINQ Query too long?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to LINQ, and don't want to over do it and make this code hard to maintain.

What do you think, is this LINQ Query too long?

```
IList<ListViewItem> data = runAnalysis.PassAnalyses.Cast<PassAnalysis>().
  Select(passAnalysis => passAnalysis.GetValue(PeakStatistics.PeakStatisticsProperty)).
  SelectMany(peakStatistics => peakStatistics.Statistics.
    Where(statisticsBase => statisticsBase.Name == statisticType).
    Select(statisticsBase => new ListViewItem {Content = statisticsBase})).ToList();
```

Comment: doing everything in 1 query is always better than in a lot of smalls.... especially with linq.

Comment: Why? None of it is actually run until you enumerate the results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say it's complicated due to nesting - but doesn't really need to be. Here's an example of a query which will give the same results (I think), but is simpler...

```
IList<ListViewItem> data = runAnalysis.PassAnalyses
      .Cast<PassAnalysis>()
      .Select(pass => pass.GetValue(PeakStatistics.PeakStatisticsProperty))
      .SelectMany(peakStats => peakStats.Statistics)
      .Where(statisticsBase => statisticsBase.Name == statisticType)
      .Select(statisticsBase => new ListViewItem {Content = statisticsBase})
      .ToList();
```

Without the nesting, it's easy to see how the transformation goes:

- Start with PassAnalyses
- Cast each item to a PassAnalysis
- Select the PeakStatistics
- From each element, select all the Statistics within it, and flatten this sequence
- Filter any statistic with the wrong name
- Convert each result into a ListViewItem
- Convert the whole sequence into a list

At this point, it's easy to convert it into a query expression:

```
IList<ListViewItem> data =
   (from PassAnalysis pass in runAnalysis.PassAnalyses
    from statsBase in pass.GetValue(PeakStatistics.PeakStatisticsProperty)
                          .Statistics
    where statsBase.Name == statisticType
    select new ListViewItem { Content = statsBase })
   .ToList();
```

Note that I've elided the first Select and the SelectMany; you could use a `let` clause if you wanted. Also I've used an explicit type for the `pass` range variable, to make the compiler generate the `Cast<PassAnalysis >()` call.

This is *slightly* different to the original version, as it will use a different form of `SelectMany` which propagates the original `pass` value too, but the results will be the same.

Calling `ToList()` at the end is somewhat ugly as there's no query expression syntax for it... but you could use an intermediate variable for that:

```
var query = ...;
IList<ListViewItem> data = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

IMO the query is fine, although it looks somewhat dense. You could reformat it a bit to be more spacey:

```
var query = from analysis in runAnalysis.PassAnalyses.Cast<PassAnalysis>()
            let value = analysis.GetValue(PeakStatistics.PeakStatisticsProperty)
            from statistic in value.Statistics
            where statistic.Name == statisticType
            select new ListViewItem { Content = statistic };

IList<ListViewItem> data = query.ToList();
```

Comment: For some reason I like the the method chaining way better.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: That's probably why we have both in C# :-)